# Laravel 4.2 services.json file is created in the root of the host

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I have converted a Laravel 5.1 project to Laravel 4.2 because it was needed to run on PHP 5.4.
Everything is alright, except the project is looking for the services.json file in the root directory of the host.
I can create this file in the root, give it permissions and the project runs. But I do not think this the proper place where the services.json file should be. As I cannot have access to the root on my server, this issue is still on.
On localhost if I run **php artisan serve** and stop it, the json file will be created in the root. But I still think it is the wrong place.

I created a plain Laravel 4.2 project to see the differences, but I couldn't find any.

Is it possible to make Laravel to place this file into the root of the project?

I'll be glad for all answers.

Thanks

```
Error message:
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
HELP
Callstack information; navigate with mouse or keyboard using Ctrl+↑ or Ctrl+↓
Copy-to-clipboard button
Exception message and its type
Code snippet where the error was thrown
Server state information
Application provided context information
 ErrorException thrown with message "file_put_contents(/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied" Stacktrace: #8 ErrorException in /home/project/staging/bootstrap/compiled.php:4000 #7 Illuminate\Exception\Handler:handleError in <#unknown>:0 #6 file_put_contents in /home/project/staging/bootstrap/compiled.php:4000 #5 Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem:put in /home/project/staging/bootstrap/compiled.php:4279 #4 Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository:writeManifest in /home/project/staging/bootstrap/compiled.php:4258 #3 Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository:compileManifest in /home/project/staging/bootstrap/compiled.php:4222 #2 Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository:load in /home/project/staging/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php:210 #1 require in /home/project/staging/bootstrap/start.php:60 #0 require_once in /home/project/staging/public/index.php:35
file_put_contents(/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
open: /home/project/staging/bootstrap/compiled.php
```

Comment: PHP 5.4 is end-of-life as of two weeks ago. It is now dangerously insecure and irresponsible to run on a public-facing server.

Comment: I am aware of that, thank you. Though I still have to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I missed one line when I converted the project from Laravel 5 to 4.2.

`app/config/app.php`, the manifest was not set up:

```
'manifest' => storage_path().'/meta',
```